# Linhas com cores alternadas

Tags: jasper-reports, relatório, jaspersoft-studio

Estou montando um relatório usando o Jaspersoft Studio, para exibir uma lista de chamados de um sistema. Esta lista possui 3 colunas, com o número do chamado, o título e a sua data de criação.

O que eu necessito é que esta listagem possua cor de fundo alternada entre suas linhas, ou seja, primeira linha fundo branco, segunda cinza claro, terceira branco e assim sucessivamente.

Porém não sei qual recurso usar ou qual regra criar.

Answer (score 2):

Coloque um retângulo com a cor transparente que você deseja ocupando toda a linha e adicione a seguinte regra no evento PrintWhenExpression:

```
$V{report_COUNT}%2 == 1 ou $V{report_COUNT}%2 == 0
```

Ou seja, ora imprime o retângulo, ora não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi Reginaldo, obrigado por estar me ajudando. Então, eu fiz como explicou e deu certo, porém eu possuo um group header por data, sendo assim, as vezes um agrupamento tem apenas um registro, ou número impar de registros, fazendo com que o primeiro registro da próxima data ( próximo agrupamento ) comece com fundo cinza e não branco.

Tem como tratar isso ?

Comment: rsrs. Já esperava a pergunta. Você pode criar uma variável,  incremente-a no evento PrintWhenExpression, resete-a quando mudar os grupos e a utilize invés de usar a report_count.

Comment: Sem querer sem abusado, tem como me mandar +/- um esboço de como ficaria essa regra ? Pq é a primeira vez que estou usando Jasper.

Obrigado !

Comment: :( Estou fazendo isso de memória de mais ou menos uns 5 anos atrás. Não tenho nada aqui agora, nem IDE, nem exemplos, nada. Esse relatório que te mandei peguei no GMAIL, por acaso. Sorry. Mas é fácil. Siga a logica ou deixe assim mesmo. Não tem problemas começar, ora colorido ora não.

Comment: Sem problemas, agradeço pela ajuda. Irei deixar o tópico aberto casa alguém tenha alguma idéia. Obrigado !